# How to clone github repo using just the username and repo name?

Tags: git, shell, github, command-line

I remember seeing this somewhere but cannot find it now. It was (maybe?) a wrapper for git that added some additional functionalities such as the ability to clone repos from GitHub by only using the username and repo name similar to AUR helpers (such as yaourt and yay) the syntax was this:

`git clone username/repo`

and it would perform clone on `https://github.com/username/repo.git`

any help will be appreciated .

Comment: Maybe [this will help you](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#_git_urls_a_id_urls_a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are talking about
[hub](https://hub.github.com/).

Comment: Yes! how did I even miss this... this is exactly what I was looking for thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a git alias that uses the native shell and concatenates the argument to a `git clone` command. Just add the following under the `[alias]` section of your `.gitconfig`:

```
hubclone = "!git clone https://github.com/${1}.git"
```

And you'd be able to use commands like this:

```
$ git hubclone apache/commons-collections
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am going with a version of your answer adapted for fish shell (~/.config/fish/functions/hub.fish):
    `function hub
        git clone 'https://github.com/'$argv'.git';
    end`

 as it best suits my use case (for now) but I am going to accept @bakarin's answer because it is actually what I was looking for and best fits as the answer to the question I asked.

edit: formatting is hard